# How to speed up a SQL query which has an IN clause that contains 4,000 elements?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using python to generate a query text which I then send to the `SQL server`. The query is created in a function that accepts a list of strings which are then inserted into the query.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB
WHERE last_word in ('red', 'phone', 'robin')
```

The issue is that here I have just 3 words, `red`, `phone`, and `robin`, but in another use case I have over 4,000 words and the response takes about 2 hours. How can I rewrite this query to make it more performant?

Comment: Where do these 4000 words come from? Ideally they'd come from the database so you could leave them there and do `where last_word in (select four_thousand_words from some_table ... )` or a join instead.

Comment: Do you have an index on `last_word`?

Answer (score 2):

optimization strategies:

1. add an index on `last_word`

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON db(last_word)
   ```
2. store the filter words in a table and use a `WHERE exists` (or inner join)

   ```
   WITH words (word) AS (
   VALUES ('red'), ('phone'), ('robin')
   )
   SELECT * 
   FROM db 
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM words WHERE word = last_word)
   ```

   or

   ```
   WITH words (word) AS (
   VALUES ('red'), ('phone'), ('robin')
   )
   SELECT db.* 
   FROM db 
   JOIN words ON db.last_word = words.word
   ```

   The `WHERE EXISTS` here should be *slightly* faster than `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

How many rows do you have in "DB"? Are there more "last_word"s matching the 4000 words in the IN clause than not? If so, it would be better to use NOT IN, to exclude instead of include. Also, try to never use SELECT * since this wildcard is very unperformant, it's better to explicitly define the columns you want to include in your query.

You could also try to put the 4000 words to match on in a (temporary) table or a CTE and then join on it, since joins usually work better than large loads of data within the IN clause. With this, I still recommend to not use the wildcard in the SELECT statement.

Comment: I have about 100,000,000 rows in DB and about 20,000 different words in "last_word"

Comment: I've added a second suggestion.

Comment: Whether `select *` is a good idea or not depends entirely on information we don’t have, and it’s secondary to the question.

Comment: @Dave on the one hand you could argue it has nothing to do with the IN clause, but since the question was how to speed up the query, I thought it would be useful to include.

Comment: @dherre65 Pretty sure that wouldn't be the gating issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB INNER JOIN WORDS_TABLE
ON DB.WORDS = WORDS_TABLE.WORDS;
```

Instead of the `*` use whatever you want to get.

`JOIN` in this case will be faster than the `IN` as you will have to write another inner query if you are using a table.

Comment: Can you show how I would build the WORDS_TABLE given the words 'red', 'phone' and 'robin' please.

Comment: @user1367204 Just create the words table with one column `words` and use that as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data into a temp table or CTE. This would make for easier addition of new data. Likewise, you’ll have to do an inner join to your source table to make sure you capture everything.

Hope this helps.